# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
if((kulax>=schodki[i][0][0] && kulax<=schodki[i][1]][0]) && (kulay==schodki[i][2][0]+10))
            spoczywa=true;
```

Hi guys, I have an array of integers which name is schodki and it is declared as int schodki[5][3][1] and the global variables : int kulax and int kulay.
     What's wrong in the line of code which is above ?

EDIT : Of course. "i" is the value from current state of loop.

Comment: As @AndreyT says, you have a syntax error, which *should* have given you a message in addition to the one you told us about. Next time, please copy-and-paste *all* relevant messages. I got `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘]’ token` on your code.

Comment: Perhaps more helpfully, you should pay attention to syntax error messages *first* before worrying about any other errors. Syntax errors can confuse the compiler, potentially making any other diagnostics meaningless.

Answer (score 8):

You have an extra `]` in

```
kulax<=schodki[i][1]][0]
```

which probably screws up parsing and results in a confusing error message. The compiler probably sees it as

```
kulax<=schodki[i][1]
```

which is indeed an attempt to compare an integer to a pointer. Try to pay attention to your own code and make sure it is free from primitive syntax errors before asking questions here.

Other than that, there's nothing wrong with your code (assuming that the variables are really declared the way you say they are)].

Comment: I thought that was a typo when making the question O_o

Comment: OMG man, take it easy. I had the same error in two places because I copied it, but I just didn't realised that the problem is so simple because I have never had this type of error which is int the topic.

Really, I spent few minutes looking on it carefully, but sometimes thing like that happens, especially in the middle of night(Poland).